# Issue sending pdf VF page in email

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, pdf

my task is to send an email with a VF page PDF attachment when a Lead is converted. With my current code, the email is sending, but the attachment comes out null with no content. What do I need to change in my code? Here is my trigger and class.

TRIGGER

```
if (trigger.isUpdate){
    for (lead ref : trigger.new){
        if (!trigger.oldMap.get(ref.id).isconverted && ref.IsConverted){
            if (ref.MAR_TAR__c != null){
                if (ref.MAR_TAR__c == 'No'){
                    MarFormEmail.sendEmail(ref.name, ref.id, ref.Facility__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CLASS

```
public class MarFormEmail {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendEmail (string referralName, id referralId, id facilityId) {

        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        user u = [select id, email from user where id = : userId];
        account acc = [select id, Administrator_s_email__c from account where id = : facilityId];
              
        PageReference ref = Page.MARRequestForm;
        ref.getParameters().put('id',referralId);
        system.debug('ref1' + ref);
        Blob b;
            if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
              b = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
            } else {
              b = ref.getContent();
            }

        // Define the email 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('MAR Form');
        efa.setBody(b);
        // Sets the paramaters of the email 
        email.setSubject( 'MAR Form' );
        email.setPlainTextBody( 'MAR Form- ' + referralName );
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {u.email};
        String[] ccaddresses = new String[] {acc.administrator_s_email__c};    
        email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        email.setccAddresses(ccaddresses);

        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});  
    
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }
}

VF PAGE (stripped down)
<apex:page standardController="Lead" renderAs="pdf">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.MAR_form_css}"/>  
        <apex:image id="marHeader11" value="{!$Resource.marHeader}" width="100%"/>

    <br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Patient Name <br/> 
            <div class = "leadInfo">
            {!lead.name}
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Date of Birth<br/> 
            <div class = "leadInfo">
            {!lead.patient_dob_formula__c}
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Social Security Number<br/> 
            <div class = "leadInfo">
            {!lead.patient_ssn__c}
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
  
    <tr colspan="3">
        <th colspan="3">Patient Address<br/> 
            <div class = "leadInfo">
            {!lead.facility__r.billingstreet}, {!lead.facility__r.billingcity} {!lead.facility__r.billingstate}, {!lead.facility__r.billingpostalcode}
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
     <br/>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: did you try `ref.getContentAsPdf()`? [Apex Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm); if that's not it, post your VF page using [edit] -- strip out the irrelevant bits

Comment: Yes I tried with ref.getContentAsPdf(), but it still comes as an empty attachment. Just added a stripped down version of the VF page below the class

Comment: try adding `efa.setContenttype('application/pdf')`

Comment: ah , i  see this could be relevant - https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/send-visualforce-as-an-email-attachment-from-apex-trigger-alternate-design/

Comment: Ah that worked! For some reason I need to use an invocable method and Process builder instead of a regular trigger. Not sure why, but it did the job. Thank you!

Comment: not sure why ...as of winter 16, getContentAsPdf is supposed to work in async context